# TFS 2010 build agent priority

Tags: build, build-automation, build-agent

I have a single build controller with many build agents strewn across many build servers.

Some build servers are more powerful than others (better CPU, more RAM, etc.). Without resorting to using "tags filter" for agent settings per build, how can i set the build agent priority?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Build agents have no Priority property, and the build controller will just pick the one from the available build agents in the pool to execute your build.

Using the tag or name filtering, as described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd647547.aspx#agents), probably helps but I understand it is not a replacement for the priority.